# filter Query not working properly with comma containing search strings in Solr

Tags: solr, special-characters, solr-query-syntax

FilterQuery is not working correct/expected when SearchString contains , (comma).

From Solr-Admin Screen:

QueryString (SearchString) - Word1,Word2 
without any queryfilter - Returns me all the results for 'Word1,word2'

QueryString (SearchString) - Word1,Word2
and Applied Queryfilter on field which is indexed, stored and multivalued.

It returns no result.

I'm just concerned that is there any known issue with queryfilter and comma containing search strings ?

Requests sent to Server

Without QF:
http://<>//text?$select=id,description,infoType,businessType,docType_t,keywords_en,title,scId,domainTypeId,nodePathString&querystring=q%3DWIPER%2CROD%26hl%3Dtrue%26hl.simple.pre%3D%3Cspan%20class%3D%27highlightSearchKeyword%27%3E%26hl.simple.post%3D%3C%2Fspan%3E%26hl.fl%3Dteaser%26sort%3Dscore%20desc%26facet.field%3D%7B!ex%3DtagForinfoType%7DinfoType%26facet%3Dtrue%26facet.mincount%3D1%26facet.field%3DnodePathText%26f.nodePathText.facet.sort%3Dindex%26f.nodePathText.facet.limit%3D-1%26computeIcons%3Dtrue&$skip=0&$top=10

With QF:
http://<>/text?$select=id,description,infoType,businessType,docType_t,keywords_en,title,scId,domainTypeId,nodePathString&querystring=q%3DWIPER%2CROD%26df%3DpartName%26qf%3DpartName%26hl%3Dtrue%26hl.simple.pre%3D%3Cspan%20class%3D%27highlightSearchKeyword%27%3E%26hl.simple.post%3D%3C%2Fspan%3E%26hl.fl%3Dteaser%26sort%3Dscore%20desc%26facet.field%3D%7B!ex%3DtagForinfoType%7DinfoType%26facet%3Dtrue%26facet.mincount%3D1%26facet.field%3DnodePathText%26f.nodePathText.facet.sort%3Dindex%26f.nodePathText.facet.limit%3D-1%26computeIcons%3Dtrue&$skip=0&$top=10

Comment: Can you please post here your query with the filter query.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `word1,word2` in double-quotes like `"word1,word2"`.

Comment: Problem solved by changing Tokenizer and Filters in Schema.xml.
Thanks for your suggestion.